# visualize rapidjson in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: rapidjson

Is there a way to visualize the information parsed in rapidjson using the visual studio debugger?
For example

`document.Parse(str.c_str());` Can I see the object and the children created?

Or if you get an array like this `auto testArray = document["test"].GetArray();` see the array elements in the debugger?

Another example - Is there a way to see the value of an object without having to do this `OutputDebugString(itr->value.GetString());`